# Why is user.save true but email shows as nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, null

I'm using a nested model form for sign-up and am working through the kinks as a beginner. One issue that popped up in particular though that I don't really get is `user.email` is returning as `nil`.

Before I started playing around with the nested model form, I could create records in the console wihtout a problem. Now, however I can't create records and some of the latest records created have `nil` as their email. (I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the nested model at all, but that's my reference point for when it started going haywire.)

If I go into `rails console` to create a new User/Profile, I follow this process:

```
user = User.new
user.email = ""
user.password = ""
user.profile = Profile.new
user.profile.first_name = ""
...
user.profile.save
user.save
```

Everything goes well until user.save, which gives me the `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'params' for #<User:>`. In `rails console` it pinpoints to user.rb:25 in `create_profile`

So here is my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password, :email
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

  validates :email, :uniqueness => true,
            :length => { :within => 5..50 },
            :format => { :with => /^[^@][\w.-]+@[\w.-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}$/i }
  validates :password, :confirmation => true,
            :length => { :within 4..20 },
            :presence => true,
            :if => :password_required?

  before_save :encrypt_new_password
  after_save :create_profile

  def self.authenticate(email, password)
    user = find_by_email(email)
    return user if user && user.authenticated?(password)
  end

  def authenticated?(password)
    self.hashed_password == encrypt(password
  end

  protected
    def encrypt_new_password
      return if password.blank?
      self.hashed_password = encrypt(password)
    end
    def password_required?
      hashed_password.blank? || password.present?
    end
    def encrypt(string)
      Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(string)
    end
  end
```

Can anyone help me figure out what's going on?

**UPDATE:** I tried changing my regex but I'm still seeing nil for email. Though a prior SO post said not to blindly copy regex without testing, so maybe I just didn't test it correctly. Good news though: I no longer get the error.

Comment: Show the code of the `create_profile` method. And why is `email` in `attr_accessor`, when it should be a field in the relevant database table?

Comment: Well, taking `:email` out of `attr_accessor` fixed the issue. Beginner's mistake in not knowing the fundamentals.

Comment: `attr_accessor` simply defines a "property" on the object and has no relation to the `attributes` (which are the fields/values obtained from a table). ActiveRecord does not save such properties.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I was using it to restate properties that were already in the database. New to programming so I appreciate the patience!

Comment: @Zabba, want to add your comment as an answer so I can give you an upvote?

Comment: Sure, I added it as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attr_accessor` simply defines a "property" on the object and has no relation to the `attributes` of a ActiveRecord model (`attributes` is a `Hash` of  the fields and values obtained from a table).

ActiveRecord does not save such "properties" as defined by the `attr_accessor`. (Essentially, `attr_accessor` defines a `attr_reader` and attr_`writer` (i.e. "getter" and "setter") at the same time)

Comment: One last thing. I've just removed the `attr_accessor` properties on my :profile, which `belongs_to :user`. Now when I go to my views, I often have errors. For example, on users#index, `<% for user in User.all %>` I get an undefined method for 'first_name' in `<%= link_to "#{user.profile.first_name} #{user.profile.last_name}", user.profile %>`. Any ideas? I'm guessing resolving these errors is better than using `attr_accessors`?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it. Though I'm wondering, since I'm a beginner, can you explain why this worked: instead of <% for user in User.all %>, I did <% @profile.each do |profile| %>. I tend to figure things out but it takes longer than I'd like and often it doesn't make sense why it eventually worked.

Comment: See this [blog post](http://paulphilippov.com/articles/enumerableeach_vs_for_loops_in_ruby) for some explanation between for and each (not sure if it will help in your case though). Also see the last comment (by Scott W. Bradley) for more clarity.

Comment: Since you're learning Rails, here is some good advice for "proper" code-quality: [Law of Demeter](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/15-the-law-of-demeter). Of course, don't follow it blindly - research the web to find the pros/cons of it too.